# Triangular Arbitrage or multiple swap arbitrage

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, flash-loans, arbitrage, floating-point

Is it posible to develop a bot with a multiple step arbitrage? like 5 swaps and above? trying my hands on triangular arbitrage with bots  on dexes, able to run a binary arbitrage. can i get a sample code that can fuel my development of a triangular arbitrage?

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you any sample code, but i suggest you to start by studying the example implementation of simple arbitrage from [Flashbots](https://www.flashbots.net/) :

https://github.com/flashbots/simple-arbitrage

Here is a Walking through the code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn8r674U1B4

After you understad well the implementation and the general concept, you can extend to a more complex cases like triangular arbitrage.